# Google assistant says app is not supported on this device in custom actions

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I have installed the Google assistant service by following the guide in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/install-sample). Now, I want to add custom actions in the SDK. 
Just to test, I used the same action and code [they have given](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/custom-actions). But, as it runs, it just says **Sorry, your app is not supported on this device** . I then wandered around in the [troubleshooting page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/troubleshooting) to find out that this was already addressed by Google. They have mentioned just about the issues caused due to triggering surface capabilities related to the screen ON. But in my case, all the surface capabilities are turned OFF. But, I'm still facing the same issue. Can anyone please help..?

Comment: Can you verify that your action package and device are using the same device model id, project, and user account?

Comment: Yes they are. I'm 100% sure..